# Disable Software Updater pop-up after 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

When I did a clean install of 16.04 with Unity on my home desktop computer, the Software Updater GUI from earlier releases seems to be gone and replaced with a discreet reminder in the upper right corner. However, when I upgraded my work desktop from 14.04 to 16.04, the Software Updater still pops up whenever there are new updates. Is there a way to disable this pop-up? I prefer to just use the terminal for updates, but the reminder in the upper right corner was pretty nice.

Software Updater GUI from earlier releases:

[image: Software Updater GUI from earlier releases]

Discreet reminder in the upper right corner:

[image: Discreet reminder in the upper right corner]

Comment: please see if there is a left-over package in this output: `dpkg -l | grep update-notifier` - at my system there are two packages: update-notifier & update-notifier-common

Comment: Yeah, I've got the same ones.

Answer (score 1):

lots of people recommend simply removing the update notifier:

```
sudo apt-get remove update-notifier
```

But that also removes the ubuntu-desktop package, so it wouldn't work in a secure way. I came up with the simplest and most brutal workaround, which is just not having that program as part of your system startup. For this, open your bashrc file

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and add at the end

```
killall update-notifier
```

It has worked so far. This file executes those commands everytime you start a new session, so it should kill the notifier as soon as you login.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! But shouldn't the line be in ~/.profile for it to be executed upon login?